# Reading a character input in the console using the Scanner Class in Java

Tags: java, character, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a character input at the console using the Scanner class, by creating a scanner object. I used two commands:

1. `char ch = sc.next(".").charAt(0);`
2. `char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);`
   I've tried both and both work well, but what's the difference between the two commands? What does the `"."` in the first command stand for?

Comment: When you want to know what a certain method from an official java class does, your first and best source is always the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next() <- Has a description of what those methods do and what the parameter in the first case is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

```
char ch = sc.next(".").charAt(0);
```

In this code it waiting to match this from this input "."